# Python: String manipulation function error, returns "None"

Tags: python, string, function

I am currently having issues with string manipulation in Python. I am trying to create a function (called nameManipulate) where it finds the beginning of each word in the string and replaces it with "n" to work with later on in the program.
I have no idea if there is a faster or more efficient method of doing this but here is mine (the random song is selected from an SQL database):

```
import sqlite3, random

db = sqlite3.connect('songsdb')
cursor = db.cursor()

number = str(random.randint(1,50))

cursor.execute('''
SELECT songid,title,artist FROM songs WHERE songid='''+number+'''
''')
all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in all_rows:
    songid = row[0] # Integer
    title = row[1] # String (song name)
    artist = row[2] # String (song artist)
print(songid, title, artist)

def nameManipulate(title):
    new_title = title
    for letter in range(len(title)):
        if title[letter] == " ":
            new_title = title.replace(str(title[letter+1]), "n")
    new_title = new_title.replace(str(title[0]), "n")
    return new_title

displayTitle = str(nameManipulate(title))

print(displayTitle)
```

The result prints the full data received by the database as expected, but it should also print the manipulated string, instead it simply prints "None".

```
37 Smells Like Teen Spirit Nirvana
None
```

Instead of "nmells Like Teen npirit", it should have printed "nmells nike neen npirit"

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated, I would love to learn exactly what's gone wrong and how to fix it. Appreciated!

Comment: Note how `nameManipulate` doesn't return anything.

Comment: After putting `return title` at the end of the function, the result simply printed the original string with no manipulation.

Comment: `title.replace` returns a new string. You need to return that new string. You'll need to fix the other use of `replace` though too, as you're throwing away the result there as well.

Comment: Yes. Strings are immutable, their methods always return new strings, which you do nothing with.

Comment: I have changed the function on the post and it seems to have somewhat fixed, however it does not manipulate the middle word of strings, for example: the song selected was "Be My Baby" and the result now returns "ne My naby" which is almost there but not quite.

Comment: @iHells In your loop, note the bit `new_title = title.replace`. I think you should be using `new_title`, not `title` on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function needed to be edited, the new_title needed to be manipulated rather than title.

```
def nameManipulate(title):
    new_title = title
    for letter in range(len(title)):
        if title[letter] == " ":
            new_title = new_title.replace(str(title[letter+1]), "<letter>")
    new_title = new_title.replace(str(title[0]), "<letter>")
    return new_title
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for using regular expressions.

If you don't know about regular expressions, it is an amazing tool to master. See [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Here is some code:

```
import re

names = [
    '37 Smells Like Teen Spirit Nirvana',
    '38 Be My Baby',
]

replaces = [
    re.sub(r' \w', ' n', name) for name in names
]

print replaces
# ['37 nmells nike neen npirit nirvana', '38 ne ny naby']
```

The method `re.sub()` receives a string describing a regular expression that you want to find (in our case, the string `' \w'` represents a whitespace followed by any character). Then we ask to replace by `' n'`, that is, a whitespace followed by n. Then we pass the string we want to replace, which is each `name` in the `names` list.

You can do much much more with regular expressions so it is worth having a detailed look.